# Is this the correct way to use SQL params?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

**My intention:**

When the user selects an artist, the *discography* combo box will fill up with the discographies that particular artist has.

---

**The Code:**

qDisco (`TSQLQuery`) is data bound to cbDisco (`TComboBox`) and contains the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT discography
FROM Album
INNER JOIN Artist 
ON Album.artist_id = Artist.id
WHERE Artist.name = :artist;
```

The `:artist` param is set by the following code:

```pascal
procedure Tmain.cbArtistChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qDisco.ParamByName('artist').Value := cbArtist.Items[cbArtist.ItemIndex];
end;
```

I have ensured that the `:artist` param stores the value of the current item of `cbArtist`, but when I compile the application, `cbDiscography` remains unfilled.

What can I do for this to work?

Comment: after you execute the query does it return anything. where have you bound the result to the other combo?

Comment: If I were to use a static value for example "Girls' Generation", the query will work, but if I use the `:artist` param, no it does not return anything. Here is an image of the bindings:
http://i7.minus.com/ibs9ExlC3sKPld.png

Comment: I'm lost here, still on Delphi 2005, so I've no XE to check. When  you say you use static do you mean qDisco.ParamByName('artist').Value := 'static'. Wondering if the type of the parameter is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of any parameter is passed to the database engine when you open the query. Changing the parameter value over a active query object have no effect until you close and re-open the data set.

Mi guess is you're not doing that last step, so change your event handler method to:

```
procedure Tmain.cbArtistChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qDisco.ParamByName('artist').Value := cbArtist.Items[cbArtist.ItemIndex];
  qDisco.Close;
  qDisco.Open;
end;
```

As you can see, this involves a full database round-trip to retrieve all the discography records associated with the current artist.